# Invisible (not hidden) files on NTFS hard disk on Mac OS

Tags: hard-drive, mac, ntfs

Short version: Some files on my external hd are only visible in Windows OS, and not on Mac OS. They are NOT simply hidden files.

Full story: I downloaded an archive of compressed images (.7z) directly to an external drive (NTFS format). I use "Paragon NTFS" software to write on the drive (downloaded specifically for this, following the HD user manual) and tried both "The Unarchiever"  and "Archive Utility" to open the compressed files on macOS.
The outcome was the following:

- Some .7z files were extracted properly, creating a folder with all the images inside.
- Some others created a folder that looks empty on Mac OS. There are no visible files inside (nor hidden files), and the folder properties show "Zero KB" as weigh, as if it was empty. If I open the same folder on Windows 10, I can clearly see all the files inside.
- If I open the .7z files on Windows, using Winrar, it works just fine, meaning it's not an issue of the downloaded archive.
- If I copy/paste one of the "empty" folders on Windows, sometimes the new folder will have visible items on Mac OS too, while some other items it doesn't.

I've already verified the integrity of the hard disk (which btw is brand new), and no errors were found.

**HD:** Seagate Backup Plus Hub Drive 6TB;

**Mac OS:** macOS Catalina (10.15.6)

**Windows OS:** Windows 10 through Bootcamp and/or Parallels VM on the same machine as macOS.

**Software used:** "The Unarchiever" (Mac) / "Archive Utility" (Mac) / Winrar (Win), "Paragon NTFS [15.5.90]" (Mac), "Parallels" (VM from Mac to Win)

Any idea why or suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Try [Keka](https://www.keka.io/en/) instead of The Unarchiver. Sometimes one util does better than another at a similar task.

Comment: BSD, in general, has always had problems with NTFS, however Paragon's filesystem software for Windows and other OSes is generally not buggy.  I've never used a Mac, so I'm not sure what they're using on the backend, but their cross-OS filesystem software generally works flawlessly. Reach out to Paragon's [tech support](https://www.paragon-software.com/support/) _(they're normally quick to reply within a day or two, but that may be extended out due to COVID)_.

Comment: I've contacted Paragon's support, waiting for their reply. Meanwhile all the "invisible" files reappeared on Mac OS too, without me doing anything. I tested with a new archive (using Keka this time), and the problem is still there, it only fixed itself on the already extracted images. I'll run some more tests to see if it has to do with restarting and or unmounting.

Answer (score 0):

NTFS support on the Mac is patchy and problematic, since always.

You would do better to use a Windows virtual machine to read the NTFS disk.

For example, you may download evaluation versions of Windows VM from Microsoft's
[Get a Windows 10 development environment](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines/).

Comment: BSD, in general, has always had problems with NTFS, however Paragon's filesystem software for Windows and other OSes is generally not buggy.  I've never used a Mac, so I'm not sure what they're using on the backend, but their cross-OS filesystem software generally works flawlessly

Comment: As I already said, I'm using Parallels as a VM, but it's a patch at best, not a solution.

Comment: If you already have a Windows VM, do you see any thing special in the properties of these invisible files? If you see nothing special, use [Streams](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/streams) to check if they have data forks.